# Is there a token not affectable by \uppercase/\lowercase and not (re-)definable in terms of \outer?

Tags: tex-core, uppercase

Is there a token not affectable by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase` and not (re-)definable in terms of `\outer`?

(If so I would like to use it as argument delimiter with things that may be used inside `\uppercase`/`\lowercase`.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by not definable in terms of outer? please show a small test document. All non-character tokens are not affected by uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Is `!` an answer, as a catcode 12 token it is not definable, and it is not affected by uppercase or lowercase with the default lccode and uccode tables. But I do not understand the question enough to be sure if this is what you mean?

Comment: Are we allowed to use LuaMetaTeX?

Comment: You should really open an account.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik there is no such token:

Each token belongs into at least one of the following two classes of tokens—active character tokens belong into both classes simultaneously:

1. Control sequences. (Control word tokens, control symbol tokens, active character tokens.) All control sequences are (re)definable in terms of `\outer`.
2. Explicit character tokens. Each explicit character token is affectable by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase` (provided its `\uccode`/`\lccode` is set accordingly).

---

In many situations you can avoid delimited arguments entirely by instead doing with undelimited arguments and checking for emptiness.

E.g., for extracting the first unelimited argument from a brace-balanced token-list I often use something like this:

```
%%   \romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{<argument>\UD@SelDOm}%
%%   yields <argument>'s 1st undlimited argument.
%%   <argument> must not be blank, i.e., must neither be empty nor consist
%%   only of explicit character tokens of catcode 10 and charcode 32.
%%
%%   \UD@SelDOm must not be defined in terms of \outer !
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{%
  \long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\z@\@secondoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
```

(`\UD@CheckWhetherNull` being defined as

```
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\z@\@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\z@\@firstoftwo}%
}%
```

or as

```
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romanumeral\ifcat$\detokenize{#1}$%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\z@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\z@\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
```

. )

With this you get:

`\romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{{A}{B}CDE\UD@SelDOm}%` → `A`.

In order to decrease the amount of iterations needed for removing everything but the first non-delimited argument I used an argument delimited by `\UD@SelDOm`. (The amount of iterations needed is: "Amount of `\UD@SelDOm` within the argument that are not nested in braces"+1).

If you don't like the `\UD@SelDOm`-delimiter as it might be defined in terms of `\outer`, then you can as follows do without—at the cost of needing more iterations until obtaining the result—the amount of iterations needed is: "Amount of undelimited arguments within the argument that themselves are not nested in braces"+1:

```
% Syntax now is: \romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{<argument>{}}%
\newcommand\UD@GrabFirst[2]{{#1}}%
\renewcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\z@\@secondoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@GrabFirst#1}}%
}%
```

E.g.,

`\romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{{A}{BC}DE{}}%` → `A`

There are many situations where you can do similar things in order to entirely avoid delimited arguments.

---

Sometimes people use as argument-delimiter the macro-token which processes the argument in question, e.g., `\def\macro#1\macro{...}`. Whether this is feasible/reasonable depends on the question whether `\macro` could be nested within its own argument and thus erroneously match up the delimiter or whether something like `\let\macrob=\macro   \outer\def\macro...` could occur.

---

---

Since you are already thinking about the question how to make macro arguments safe, I would like to note that there are other traps besides `\outer\def...` and `\uppercase`/`\lowercase`:

1. For example the question whether a macro-mechanism based on
   delimited arguments, which shall handle (almost) arbitrary arguments
   given by the user, should work inside a tabular environment/within
   an alignment.

   Assume, e.g., a macro `\grabdelimited` which processes a delimited
   argument and which the user uses for gathering and detokenizing the
   characters `B` and `&`.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \def\grabdelimited#1\delimiter{Arguments grabbed: \detokenize{#1}}%
   \begin{document}
   \grabdelimited B&\delimiter

   \makeatletter
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
   %A&\relax\grabdelimited B&\delimiter\\
   A&\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\grabdelimited B&\delimiter}
   \end{tabular}
   \end{document}
   ```

   The first/commented line inside the tabular-environment would yield
   an error, the second does not because here the `&` belonging to the
   delimited argument is hidden inside the curly braces of
   `\@firstofone`.
2. Yet another problem might be passing unbalanced
   `\if...`/`\else`/`\fi` as macro-arguments which might erroneously
   match up some `\if...`/`\else` that occur in the definitions of the
   macros that process those arguments.

   Same with unbalanced `\csname`/`\endcsname`.

Answer (score 1):

*Extended comment:*

If you're really afraid that your end-of-argument marker might get affected by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase` you just have to make sure that it doesn't appear on top level so that it is never seen by `\uppercase` or `\lowercase`. This could be achieved by making sure that it is only inserted in a context where expansion can't stop in between, e.g., by using a `\romannumeral` expansion context. The following sets up a macro which uses the character `D` as the end-of-argument marker, but since it expands further that marker is never left in the input stream such that it could be affected by `\lowercase` or `\uppercase`:

```
% first insert a \romannumeral such that the following is expanded as far as possible
\newcommand*\mymacro{\romannumeral\mymacro@a}
% only after \romannumeral has started input the delimiter
\newcommand\mymacro@a[1]{\mymacro@b #1D}
```

Then `\mymacro@b` could process the argument in an expandable manner and use `D` as the delimiter. And you could end the `\romannumeral` expansion context with `\z@`. Of course you could still expand `\mymacro` once and then expand `\mymacro@a` with `\expandafter` without starting `\romannumeral` such that the `D` could get affected by `\lowercase` (with `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lowercase\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter\mymacro{}}`), but at least now this has to be created with malicious intent.

You can never protect yourself against an `\outer` redefinition but people redefining internals of other people's code as `\outer` seem to not want to have working code, so maybe this is no case you have to protect yourself against.